# How to visualize all ways of method calls

Tags: java

Can I get a scheme with my method calls tree?

I want to see tree of my method calls, with classes as levels.

Does tools like this exist?

Comment: stacktrace??...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, a stack trace pretty much would already seem to cover your requirements.  If you are asking this in the context of catching an exception, then logging the exception would record the stack trace of method calls leading up the method where the actual problem occurred.

If you're not asking this in the concept of catching an exception, then you can still run your code in debug mode and attach the IDE.  Then, you should have visibility into the series of method calls behind each method being executed.

Answer (score 0):

You can look for open call hierarchy or show references in the workspace by right clicking on the method, if you are using eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [Callgraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_graph) - Doxygen can do that, with JavaDoc you may try this [project on Github](https://github.com/gousiosg/java-callgraph)

Answer (score 0):

You could just also right click the method your interested in and click open call hierarchy or show references in the workspace project or working set. These are default with **eclipse**.